# Powershell - Test-Path with Import-CSV - remove @{Path= when importing

Tags: powershell

I am creating simple powershell to grab data from a CSV(list of directories) and pass it into Test-Path to check if the path exists.  However, the path from the csv is passing in...differently.
$csvdata = Import-Csv "C:\X\testfolder.csv"

foreach($entry in $csvdata){

```
If(Test-Path "'($entry)'"){
    Write-Host $entry ' Folder exists'
}
Else{
    Write-Host ($entry) ' Folder does not exist'
}
```

}

test-path "C:\X\testfolder.csv"

This is what I get
@{Path=C:\X}  Folder does not exist
@{Path=C:\X\testing}  Folder does not exist

Obviously, the issue is the "@{Path=" being passed in. Is there a proper way to grab those rows or should I remove them after the fact? If so, how?
Thank you.

Comment: `$entry` -> `$entry.Path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `$entry` object represents *an entire row*. To get just the value of a particular column, use the column header as a property name, eg.:

```
Write-Host "Folder '$($entry.Path)' does not exist"
```